# .htaccess not rewriting the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I have one url that I cannot get to rewrite

I am trying to rewrite `/section45l` to `/services/incentives/section45l` using the following rule.

```
RewriteRule ^section45l$ /services/incentives/section45l
```

But it's not working.

Comment: How not working? Gives error? What does it do?

Comment: Returns the 404 error document

Comment: Then `/services/incentives/section45l` doesn't exist.

Comment: Does  **/services/incentives/section45l** uri exist ?

Comment: Actually I need to rewrite "/section-45l/" and "/section-45l" to services/incentives/section45l

Comment: Yes.  apolloenergiesinc.com/services/incentives/section45l

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? is it in root or subfolder?

Comment: Sorry, it's in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following  :

```
RewriteRule ^section45l/?$ /services/incentives/section45l [L,NC]
```

Note the **?** in pattern ,it makes the preceding char optional ,so the rule would also match **/section45l** .

Comment: I tried that thinking the same thing.  I even wrote it that way.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Don'tr know if you know by my hosting provider had me install Joomla 3.5.1 from v1.5 and it essentially overwrote my existing file structure.  So now I have 6 years of search results that are failing after I rebuilt the site.  This old url is what the search campaign links to.

Answer (score 0):

Using rewrite rules in .htaccess is probably not the easiest way to fix this.

I recommend using the Redirect component which is built in to the latest versions of Joomla:

- enable the "System - Redirect" plugin with "Collect URLs" = Enabled
- wait for a few days
- in `Components -> Redirect`, sort the results by clicking on the "404 Hits" column title until the most common 404 hits are at the top
- edit each of the top results, enter the appropriate redirect address, enable the redirect and save
- once you are done you can set "Collect URLs" = Disabled in the "System - Redirect" plugin and click the "Purge Unpublished" button in `Components -> Redirect` to clear the collected URLs you are ignoring